# Possible to invert the randomForest function in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I computed a random forest to predict a target value in a large data structure.
The matrix contains some thousand rows, about 20 input variables and one output/target/response variable.

For example, the dataframe df is like:

```
| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | ... | Rsp |
---------------------------------
|  1 |  8 |  2 |  3 | ... | 1.5 |
|  2 |  4 |  3 |  4 | ... | 1.3 |
|  5 |  7 |  6 |  3 | ... | 1.4 |
|  2 |  8 |  8 |  4 | ... | 1.9 |
|  9 |  3 |  1 |  6 | ... | 2.1 |
   .    .    .    .    .     .
```

I calculated the forest:

```
df.r <- randomForest(Rsp ~ . , data = df , subset = train , mtry = 50, ntree=200)
p <- predict(df.r, df[-train,])
```

I want to minimize the response in order to get the best combinations of input variables. But because the input and output are noisy, I cannot directly take the variables at the minimum response value.

So my question is: Is it possible to go the tree bottom-up? Is it possible to get the combinations of variables which give me a low response value?

Comment: A random-forest contains an ensemble of tree models and the majority (or model average) result is used for prediction. Which tree would you like to go `bottom-up` in? Number 1? 2? 200? In a single tree it is possible, in a random forest, each observationer would result in a vector of length 200, one for each tree. Which to use it not clearly defined.

Comment: **I want to minimize the response in order to get the best combinations of input variables** or **I want to get the best combinations of input variables in order to minimize the response**?

Comment: The last one. Hey, I'm not a native english speaker.